# Finding the probability of three true or false answers, two of them being true

Tags: probability

I'm trying to wrap my head around this probability question:

`A quiz consists of three true or false questions. What is the probability that there are exactly two true answers?`

Question 1, 2, and 3 can either be true or false. So this makes the chances of every question being true, 1/2 chance.

The question is asking for two true answers, so I thought it would be 1/2 * 1/2. 1/4 being the chance that two of the three questions are true. But the answer is 3/8. I have no idea why that's the correct answer. Could someone please explain?

Comment: The possible cases are $TTF, TFT, FTT$.  Each has probability $\frac 18$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly two true means exactly one wrong, so either first wrong, second wrong, or third wrong, each has a possibility of (1/2)^3, summing to 3/8